# Opensuse udev device does not start systemd when replugged-in

Tags: linux, opensuse, systemd, udev

I'm trying to create an automatic backup system when an external hard drive plugged in :

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/300-backup-projects.rules
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0480", ATTRS{idProduct}=="b202", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="backup_projects.service"
```

---

```
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/backup_projects.service
[Unit]
Description=Backup Projects Folder
BindsTo=run-media-user-Backup\x20EXT.mount
After=run-media-user-Backup\x20EXT.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/backup.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=run-media-user-Backup\x20EXT.mount
```

And the backup.sh file : ( just testing )

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 2;

echo $(date) > /run/media/user/Backup\x20EXT/data.txt
```

When I run `sudo systemctl start backup_projects.service` the dada.txt file get created. But when I replug-in the external hard drive, nothing happen.

It turned out that the service stopped when the file get created.

I don't know if I'm messing something ?

Comment: Do you see your hard drive in "systemctl -t device list"?